# How to Recognize jQuery .change() on Select List in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are several questions about this on SO ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122009/select-element-and-jquery-change-event-in-ie8),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512326/why-doesnt-jquery-change-select-options-in-ie),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208471/getting-jquery-to-recognise-change-in-ie),[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637503/jquery-change-event-on-select-not-firing-in-ie/4200272)), but all are extremely old and unhelpful.

This code works flawlessly in Chrome & Firefox, but how can I get Internet Explorer to cooperate? Right now in IE, you click a select option and it does nothing. Some have proposed .click() but that doesn't establish whether or not there was a change in the selected option, even though I couldn't seem to get .click() to work in IE11 anyway.

Any suggestions?

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.block-webform').hide();
  $('#contact-select option[value="select"]').attr("selected", "selected");

  $('#contact-select').change(function() {
    $('.block-webform').slideUp(600);
    $('#' + $(this).val()).slideDown(600);
  });
});
```

```css
.block-webform {
  height: 30px;
  margin: 30px;
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="contact-select">
  <option value="select" selected="selected">- Select Reason for Contact -</option>
  <option value="block-webform-client-block-1" name="1">General Question</option>
  <option value="block-webform-client-block-2" name="2">Update Information</option>
  <option value="block-webform-client-block-3" name="3">Question About Order</option>
</select>

<div id="block-webform-client-block-1" class="block-webform">General Question</div>
<div id="block-webform-client-block-2" class="block-webform">Update Information</div>
<div id="block-webform-client-block-3" class="block-webform">Question About Order</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9h7jLe64/1/

Comment: Works fine in IE here.

Comment: @WaleedIqbal, try it on my live demo site: http://dev.gmsaa.org/contact

Comment: It's working in IE too. Anyways you can try changing it to  `$('#contact-select').off().on('change',function() });`

Comment: Can also confirm this works fine in IE10 & 11. If you are having issues, please edit the question to describe them and give the working code that produces them.

Comment: @WebMW it's working properly in this  [link] (http://dev.gmsaa.org/contact) site too. Even in IE browser.

Comment: What!? I don't understand why it's not working in my IE11.

Comment: Check the console for errors

Comment: @SushilShrestha or anyone, could you please clear cache and try my demo link again? I had to revert it back to where it was in its original working state for Chrome & Firefox. This still does not work for me in IE11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gmsaa.js giving error

```
var url = new URL(document.location);
```

Object doesn't support this action.

That's why your change function is not working.

Change it to

```
var url = location.href;
```

Edit 2:

Add this function at top of js file

```
function gup( name, url ) {
            if (!url) url = location.href;
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
            var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
            var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
            var results = regex.exec( url );
            return results == null ? null : results[1];
        }
```

Change this code

```
var url = location.href;
        var form = gup("form");
        jQuery('#contact-select option[name="'+form+'"]').attr("selected", "selected");
        var formvalue = jQuery('#contact-select option[name="'+form+'"]').attr('value');
        jQuery('#' + formvalue).show();
        jQuery('#contact-select').change(function(){
            jQuery('.region-content .block-webform').slideUp(600);
            jQuery('#' + jQuery(this).val()).slideDown(600);
            callResize();
        });
```

Comment: Wow! Really hoping this is the cause. Just made the change but a new error popped up a couple lines further down... "Unable to get property 'get' of undefined or null reference".... any idea?

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters

Comment: check Haim Evgi answer

Comment: This answer unfortunately sets me back even further... Changing to var url = location.href; broke all browsers. Just reverted back to what works in Chrome & Firefox... even though several here said it was working in IE11 for them.... I am very confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wow, you did it! I still don't understand why the demo was working for other people testing with IE11, but this works! Thank you for helping me out on this. I was sincerely lost after a few hours of banging my head.